# How can I find tendencies in specific cases between two groups?

Tags: spss, t-test

I'm doing this project where we are investigating whether social networks can influence peoples distinctiveness. Briefly summarized, we have primed a group with a social media and another is the control group. Afterwards, they were given a questionnarie where they have...

1. Written 12 identity elements
2. Rated these elements on how central they are to their identity on a likert-scale from 1-7 where seven is very central to their identity (this scale is used throughout)
3. Rated these elements on how a) different they make them b) how it constitutes a special social role and c) how seperated these elements make them. We are not using the words further, just their ratings.

So far so good.

We have alot of variables in our database:

1. Age
2. Sex
3. Priming or control-group
4. Centrality of the elements (the mean of 2 questions about the centrality asked in different ways) (12 variables)
5. How different it makes them (12 variables)
6. How "roly" it makes them (12 variables)
7. How separated it makes them (12 variables)

The way I have tackled this so far:
Found the mean of centrality for each element, multiplied it by variable 5-6-7 (look up) casewise and squarerooted the number (gives a 1-7 number). Then the mean of these three new variables (CentralityXDifference, CentralityXRole, CentralityXSeperateness) gives us a number of "Total distinctiveness". Unfortunately these means don't differ depending on priming or controlgroup, but that's okay. We can probably argue why.

Here comes some questions

1. What do i do if I want to check for tendencies that the priming or controlgroup accordingly have high scores in variable 5-6-7 when they have high in variable 4; Do the priming group tend to rate elements of high centrality as highly distinctive? I cannot figure out a way to do this in a smart way, so if you have an idea i'll be grateful.
2. Have I done something wrong the way i've done it already?  Is there room for improvement in my method?

Answer (score 1):

For 1, for simplicity, just consider variable 5, difference.  For the other two, you would do the same thing.

Calculate the correlation (within each subject across elements) between centrality and difference.  That gives you one measure per subject (the correlation).  You can use whatever flavor of correlation floats your boat, but probably rank correlation is the right thing here.  Then take the mean correlation across subjects but within treatment/control.  You now have mean correlation in treatment and mean correlation in control.  If the mean is bigger for treatment, that says that people who are primed have a greater tendency to to assign higher difference to elements for which they assign higher centrality (and vice versa of course)

Now you just do a t-test for the difference in means between treatment and control.  If you are the kind of guy who gets tense about the fact that the data you are putting into the t-test is not normally distributed (you shouldn't be that kind of guy, but some people just are that kind of guy), then you will not like the t-test here.  Correlations have to be between -1 and 1, so they sure ain't normal.

But, there are other tests.  I like the Wilcoxon rank-sum test (also called Mann-Whitney U test), for example.  So, use that if you're that kind of guy.

Comment: But wouldn't a correlation between centrality and difference be high, if subjects for example had low centrality and low difference? Then the correlation would be misleading...? Or have i understood correlations wrong?

Comment: I think that is what you want, though.  if their centrality is above average when their difference is above average, then their centrality is below average when their difference is below average.  Just as a matter of arithmetic.  Because both centrality and difference have to be equal to their averages, on average. Like the fact that tall people have above average basketball skills implies that short people have below average basketball skills.